# IT Management questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

What's the best place to ask questions about IT management related things. For example, getting to PCI compliance, how to hire someone, process flow, dealing with gantt charts, what kind of reporting metrics are useful, etc...? 
These don't seem to fit into any of the stack exchanges.

Comment: I've been wondering about this myself recently.  I wonder if the [Software Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering) SE site would be a good fit?

Comment: I've posted a bunch of topics to the IT Management Area51, I feel it's a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current closest proposal is probably: [IT Careers & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers-training) (but that's only a partially applicable - nothing about e.g. metrics there).

You *could* start your own Area 51 proposal but you might be better off combining your efforts with that Q&A. Just a thought...

**Update:** I tell a lie - the closest is: [IT Management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7502/it-management). *Grin.*

**Update 2:** You could now post some of your questions on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposed site for this at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7502/it-management).

Comment: Perfect, I'll try and suggest a bunch of questions by the end of the week. Any ideas where to get answers in the mean-time? :p

Comment: @user142287 - do you have a trusted manager / coach, even in another profession, who can help? Many questions span multiple branches. If not, ask your network of existing contacts if they know anyone. Then take the manager out to lunch (you pay) and ask all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer all those questions?  A 4 year degree in MIS/BCS/BMA is a good place to start.  :).  That and Google things like "What is PCI compliance and should I care?"

IMHO, There is no perfect metric, the metric/reporting is only as valuable as what you interpret it as and what actions you take.  Your business will determine what is valuable to you. For example:

Small manufacturing company has 5 developers for maintaining systems that track progress through the floor may have less concern for a code coverage/churn report than a large financial system with 50 developers that is responsible for the execution of millions of transactions with pinpoint accuracy may be a bit more concerned about dotting the crossing the t's and dotting the lower case j's.  Same report can give you the same metrics, it's just what is most valuable.

I know it's not a Stack Exchange related site (and somewhat a competitor) but Experts Exchange seems to have a lot of good info there.

Last thought, if you're dealing with MS related technologies (well even if not), there are gems of genius through the examples and online labs that give you more real life situations of how to manage and as a result determine what metrics you want.  Some are out there for various industries already that they encourage you to tweak to your business model.  Channel 9 (Microsoft) also provides some indirect information.

SCOM may be a good place to just start.  When people think IT, they usually think infrastructure and helpdesk.  :)